# how to set thumbnail width and height with lightSlider

Tags: jquery

I want to set height and width of thumbnail image in lightslider on URL:

http://agentpet.com/ver1/index.php/user/get_pet_details/84

Below is my current code:

```
$('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
        gallery:true,
        item:1,
        loop:true,
        thumbItem:9,

        slideMargin:0,
        enableDrag: false,
        currentPagerPosition:'left',
        onSliderLoad: function(el) {
            el.lightGallery({

                selector: '#imageGallery .lslide'
            });

        }   
    });
```

Kindly help me out how i can set height and width to thumbnails that are appearing under big image ?

Comment: you can use this css and control it "ul.lSGallery li img{max-height : 50px; max-width : 100px;}"

Comment: This also not working

Comment: try this
ul.lSGallery li img {
    height: 50px !important;
}

Answer (score 4):

Simple:  in `lightslider.css` look for `.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery img{}`

It would be on 140th line probably under img just set the `height 50px;` and `width:100%;`

That's it!! it would set the size of thumbnail in lightslider no matter what the aspect ratio of your image!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the width you have to decrease the thumbItem value, b/c plugin set the width on the basis of thumbItem count.

Answer (score 1):

Like Aniket Nagapure, you havet o change `lightslider.css` But if you do not want the image to be deformed, in `lightslider.css` look for `.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery li{}` and add `height: 50px;` then, in `.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSGallery img{}` add `width: 100%;` and `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

verticalHeight and vThumbWidth works when we have vertical property set to true, in my case it is false and hence these two attributes are working for width and height. Also, i tried Jquery option ($(".lSGallery li").css("width", 100 + "px").css("height", 100 + "px")) as well as CSS option (ul.lSGallery li img{max-height : 50px; max-width : 100px;}). Neither of them working.

Answer (score -1):

LightSlider has an option to set the width and height thumbnails called [`verticalHeight`](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/settings.html) and [`vThumbWidth`](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/settings.html). If those are not what you need then you could manually set the width and height using `jquery`

```
$(".lSGallery li").css("width", 100 + "px").css("height", 100 + "px")
```

Comment: verticalHeight and vThumbWidth works when we have vertical property set to true, in my case it is false and hence these two attributes are working for width and height. Also, i tried Jquery option ($(".lSGallery li").css("width", 100 + "px").css("height", 100 + "px")) as well as CSS option (ul.lSGallery li img{max-height : 50px; max-width : 100px;}). Neither of them working.